# Parsing JSON DATA in AWS

Tags: json

I still cannot parse JSON data in linux.
I need a linux command to parse Json data to readable string.

someone told me to use underscore-cli.(https://npmjs.org/package/underscore-cli)

I install and use it, still the result is unreadable.

my data:
"2005\u5e7405\u670812\u65e5(\u6728) 02\u664216\u5206"

according to this link
http://json.parser.online.fr/

the result is 
"2005年05月12日(木) 02時16分"

Is there any other way to parse this Json data?
Please help.

Comment: is there any chance that I can convert this data using perl?

Answer (score 0):

Try jq: http://stedolan.github.com/jq/

```
echo  '"2005\u5e7405\u670812\u65e5(\u6728) 02\u664216\u5206"' | ./jq .
"2005年05月12日(木) 02時16分"
```

jq takes escaped unicode and outputs it in utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

For python users with any python 3 env:

```
python -m json.tool
```

It will take json input from stdin and print out json nicely.

To test, say you have a json file: test.json. And pass to grep to grep your_key:

```
cat test.json | python -m json.tool
cat test.json | python -m json.tool | grep 'your_key'
```

Say you have output from a curl:

```
curl -s 'https://api.github.com/users/lambda' | python -m json.tool
```